# Можно ли в select использовать данные из txt файла?

Tags: mysql

Есть txt файл,  где через  ; перечислены id и др.информация. Задача вывести из таблицы main все фио чьи id совпадает с id из файла. Вопрос:  могу ли я не заводя спец. таблицу (потому что прав нет) выполнить такой запрос? И если да,  то подскажите как?
Буду очень благодарна за любую информацию)

Comment: Все, что Вам может помочь - это конструкция `LOAD DATA INFILE` но она все равно требует таблицу

Comment: Используйте любой язык программирования (можно даже bash), чтобы вытащить ID и уже потом отправляйте запрос.

Answer (score 1):

Сколько строк в текстовом файле?
Из наиболее простых вариантов вижу следующий:
Открываете ваш txt файл в Excel через меню "Данные" -> "Из текста". Далее в мастере указываете разделитель ";". Не забудьте указать текстовый тип данных если ID может начинаться с нуля.

Далее в Excel создаете текст запроса следующего рода:

```
select Ваш_ID1 id, поле1, поле2 from dual union all    
select Ваш_ID2 id, поле1, поле2 from dual union all    
select Ваш_ID3 id, поле1, поле2 from dual union all    
select Ваш_IDn id, поле1, поле2 from dual
```

Сделать это довольно легко с использованием функции СЦЕПИТЬ
Далее полученную конструкцию помещаете в SQL запрос к вашей БД.

Например,

```
with txt as (
select Ваш_ID1 id, поле1, поле2 from dual union all    
select Ваш_ID2 id, поле1, поле2 from dual union all    
select Ваш_ID3 id, поле1, поле2 from dual union all    
select Ваш_IDn id, поле1, поле2 from dual     
)

select main.fio, main.id from    
main join txt on main.id=txt.id
```

Comment: Пока точно не знаю(завтра только получу),  но предполагаю что много. Там в каждой строке id и ссылка,  все разделено через ; .